# Windmill in Python hanging when using getPageText()

Tags: javascript, python, windmill

I'm trying to write a simple script with Windmill to open a page (which has javascript) and then download the entire html.  My code is:

```
from windmill.authoring import setup_module, WindmillTestClient
from windmill.conf import global_settings
import sys

global_settings.START_FIREFOX = True
setup_module(sys.modules[__name__])

def my_func():
    url = "a certain url"
    client = WindmillTestClient(__name__)
    client.open(url=cur_url)
    html = client.commands.getPageText()
```

This last line, with getPageText() just seems to hang.  Nothing happens and it never returns.

Also, is it necessary for windmill to open up the whole GUI every time?  And if it is, is there a function in python to close it when I'm done (a link to any actual documentation would be helpful; all I've found are a few examples)?

Edit: solved the problem by just using Selenium instead, took about 15 minutes vs 3 hours of trying to make Windmill work.
A colleague of mine came up with an alternate solution, which was to actually watch the network traffic coming into the browser and scrape the GET requests. Not totally sure how he did it though.